# Finding the average length of a column as per a particular case in MySQL

Tags: mysql, case, average

I have a table of Users and another table of the Messages they've sent and I'm trying to find the average length of a message and the average length of a message if the user is retired. If I try this:

```
SELECT u.id, 
AVG(LENGTH(m.body)) AS avg_msg_length, 
AVG(LENGTH(CASE m.is_retired WHEN true THEN m.body ELSE NULL END)) AS avg_msg_length_retired 
FROM Users u LEFT OUTER JOIN Messages m 
ON u.id = m.sender_id 
GROUP BY u.id;
```

In the result I get the average length fine but the average length for retired people is just a column of NULLs.

If I try this:

```
SELECT u.id, 
AVG(LENGTH(m.body)) AS avg_msg_length, 
AVG(LENGTH(CASE m.is_retired WHEN "true" THEN m.body ELSE NULL END)) AS avg_msg_length_retired 
FROM Users u LEFT OUTER JOIN Messages m 
ON u.id = m.sender_id 
GROUP BY u.id;
```

I get,

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column '“true”' in 'field list'.

I find this extremely strange since the is_retired field is a varchar.

Am I using the CASE WHEN incorrectly inside the LENGTH? I tried the second form of CASE WHEN too as:

```
 AVG(LENGTH(CASE WHEN m.is_retired=true THEN m.body ELSE NULL END)) AS avg_msg_length_retired
```

and,

```
AVG(LENGTH(CASE WHEN m.is_retired="true" THEN m.body ELSE NULL END)) AS avg_msg_length_retired
```

And get the same results as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer the `length()` inside the `case`:

```
SELECT u.id, 
       AVG(LENGTH(m.body)) AS avg_msg_length, 
       AVG(CASE WHEN m.is_retired = 'Y' THEN LENGTH(m.body) END) AS avg_msg_length_retired 
FROM Users u LEFT OUTER JOIN
     Messages m 
     ON u.id = m.sender_id 
GROUP BY u.id;
```

The `'Y'` should be whatever character or string indicates truth.

The problem with your query is that you are mixing character expressions (`is_retired`) with numeric expressions (`true`).  Be consistent with the types.

For instance, this evaluates to false:

```
 select 'true' = true;
```

But this evaluates to true:

```
select 1 = true;
```

Comment: Getting the length inside worked. However the error was arising from the query that was already using double quotes around the true. The error was caused by the incorrect sequence of commands I think. Thanks anyhow!